# How the alter expression based on variable?

Tags: python

I'm using the SymPy `coeff` feature and would like to adjust my expression based on a variable (dimension).

If dimension equals 2, then

```
y = expr.coeff(v[0],0).coeff(v[1],0)
```

If dimension equals 3, then

```
y = expr.coeff(v[0],0).coeff(v[1],0).coeff(v[2],0)
```

How can I generalize this to allow for arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate on the quantity of dimensions.  Let's call it `dim`

```
y = expr
for i in range(dim):
    y = y.coeff(v[i], 0)
```

This "walks" y down the list of coefficients, one at a time.

Comment: I disagree: "dumb question" is the one you *don't* ask.  This one takes a spoonful of lateral thinking.